# playwrigh json reporter adds control characters

Tags: playwright

This is part of the json output report contains the escape character `\u001b`.
Is there a way to avoid it so the message will be more readable?

I'm using Version 1.39

`"message": "\u001b[2mexpect(\u001b[22m\u001b[31mreceived\u001b[39m\u001b[2m).\u001b[22mtoStrictEqual\u001b[2m(\u001b[22m\u001b[32mexpected\u001b[39m\u001b[2m) // deep equality\u001b[22m\n\n\u001b[32m- Expected  - 1\u001b[39m\n\u001b[31m+ Received  + 1\u001b[39m\n\n\u001b[33m@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@\u001b[39m\n\u001b[2m  Array [\u001b[22m\n\u001b[32m-   \"ID1\",\u001b[39m\n\u001b[31m+   \"ID\",\u001b[39m\n\u001b[2m    \"Title\",\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \"Protocol\",\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \"Timestamp (GMT +2)\",\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \"Duration (seconds)\",\u001b[22m\n\u001b[2m    \"Traffic (bytes)\",\u001b[22m",`

Comment: What's your OS and terminal you're viewing this on?

Comment: Using macOS. opening the file in an IDE, sublime text or browser for example shows the same format.